# how do i use the list functions for the linq query?

Tags: c#, linq, list, collections, linq-to-entities

I'm making a query and I want to search the DB for "Branchid" (pic2) that is in the "RentsOrder" (pic2) table but as I add the dot in the query after the RentsOrders (pic1) I get a list of collection functions and I don't know how to use them to go on the list and find the BarnchId that equals to the BranchId prop

You can see that in the CarType when I added the dot I did get the "Year" prop

[image: pic1]

[image: pic2]

Comment: Which one? I think you have 1:n relation from car to RentsOrder.

Comment: Please post [actual code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), not screenshots of code. Please explain clearly what you are trying to do, what happens when you try, and how that's different from what you expected or wanted. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for advice on how to present your question in a clear, answerable way.

Comment: henk - that is right i do have 1:n you can see it in pic2 thats not a problem I just dont know how to run on all of the orders BranchId so I can compare them to the prop BranchId that the user send me......

Comment: You are attempting to run before you can walk. I suggest you do some research into Linq and Lambda. What you are doing there is mixing the two paradigms and that's why you are getting confused.  Pick one or the other until you understand how to use them together.

Comment: James - Tell me something I don't know I know i'm a bit confused that's the reason i'm here asking....... want to explain why i'm confused...... as you can see I did have successes when I did the "endRent" and "startRent"

Peter - as you can see people here understand....

Comment: @Theiceman, have a look at the post below. It should help shed some light.  You are using syntax that you don't fully understand.  Once you understand why you are using x, or why you are using z, you will realize that what you need to do in order to get a RentOrder, isn't much different.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
var query _db.Cars
    .Where
    (
        z => z.CarType.Year == Year &&
        z.CarType.Gear == Gear &&
            z.RentOrders
            .Max
            (
                x => x.ActualEndDate
            ) < startRent &&
            z.RentOrders
            .Max
            (
                x => x.ActualEndDate
            ) < endRent &&
        z.CarType.Manufacture.ManufactureName == manufactureName &&
        z.RentOrders.Where(x => x.BranchId == BranchId).ToList()
    ).ToList();
```

I do recommend that you try to get more acquainted with Lambda and Linq.  The => lambda operator allows you to access the single instance properties of the object. Similarly to how you use z, or x to access the properties of their associated objects.

So where you have a collection of RentOrders, a single instance would be 1 of those in the collection.

Refer to the following for further detail: [=> Operator (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311046.aspx)

Comment: Hi James - First thank you ! second I already tried it, it brings me a compilation error:

Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<CarRent.BL.RentsOrder>'

from what I understand the lambda expression gives back a bool ??

Comment: You are very welcome. No.  Lambda or Linq will give you back whatever you are querying for depending on what you are attempting to do.

Comment: Could you please post the exception and the full query that you are attempting to perform?  Because what I posted should have done the trick unless you added additional constraints.

Comment: Replace your existing query with the one I added, and let me know what exception it throws, if any.

Comment: Sorry, use the one I just replaced it with.